# Fit Amplitude (Frequency response) of a capacitor with lmfit

Tags: curve-fitting, complex-numbers, lmfit

I am trying to fit measured data with lmfit.
My goal is to get the parameters of the capacitor with an equivalent circuit diagram.
So, I want to create a model with parameters (C, R1, L1,...) and fit it to the measured data.

I know that the resonance frequency is at the global minimum and there must also be R1. Also known is C.
So I could fix the parameter C and R1. With the resonance frequency I could calculate L1 too.

I created the model, but the fit doesn't work right.

Maybe someone could help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters
from lmfit import report_fit
params = Parameters()

params.add('C', value = 220e-9, vary = False)
params.add('L1', value = 0.00001, min = 0, max = 0.1)
params.add('R1', value = globalmin, vary = False)
params.add('Rp', value = 10000, min = 0, max = 10e20)
params.add('Cp', value = 0.1, min = 0, max = 0.1)

def get_elements(params, freq, data):
    C = params['C'].value
    L1 = params['L1'].value
    R1 = params['R1'].value
    Rp = params['Rp'].value
    Cp = params['Cp'].value
    
    XC = 1/(1j*2*np.pi*freq*C)
    XL = 1j*2*np.pi*freq*L1
    XP = 1/(1j*2*np.pi*freq*Cp)
    
    Z1 = R1 + XC*Rp/(XC+Rp) + XL
    
    real = np.real(Z1*XP/(Z1+XP))
    imag = np.imag(Z1*XP/(Z1+XP))
    
    model = np.sqrt(real**2 + imag**2)
    
    #model = np.sqrt(R1**2 + ((2*np.pi*freq*L1 - 1/(2*np.pi*freq*C))**2))
    #model = (np.arctan((2*np.pi*freq*L1 - 1/(2*np.pi*freq*C))/R1)) * 360/((2*np.pi))
    
    return data - model

out = minimize(get_elements, params , args=(freq, data))

report_fit(out)


#make reconstruction for plotting
C = out.params['C'].value
L1 = out.params['L1'].value
R1 = out.params['R1'].value
Rp = out.params['Rp'].value
Cp = out.params['Cp'].value


XC = 1/(1j*2*np.pi*freq*C)
XL = 1j*2*np.pi*freq*L1
XP = 1/(1j*2*np.pi*freq*Cp)
Z1 = R1 + XC*Rp/(XC+Rp) + XL
real = np.real(Z1*XP/(Z1+XP))
imag = np.imag(Z1*XP/(Z1+XP))

reconst = np.sqrt(real**2 + imag**2)
reconst_phase = np.arctan(imag/real)* 360/(2*np.pi)




'''
PLOTTING
'''

#plot of filtred signal vs measered data (AMPLITUDE)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40,15))
file_title = 'Measured Data'
plt.subplot(311)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlim([min(freq), max(freq)])
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.xlabel('Frequency in Hz')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.plot(freq, z12_fac, 'g', alpha = 0.7, label = 'data')


#Plot Impedance of model in magenta
plt.plot(freq, reconst, 'm', label='Reconstruction (Model)')
plt.legend()


#(PHASE)
plt.subplot(312)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim([min(freq), max(freq)])
plt.ylabel('Phase in °')
plt.xlabel('Frequency in Hz')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.plot(freq, z12_deg, 'g', alpha = 0.7, label = 'data')

#Plot Phase of model in magenta
plt.plot(freq, reconst_phase, 'm', label='Reconstruction (Model)')
plt.legend()


plt.savefig(file_title)
plt.close(fig)
```

[measured data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op2ZN.png)
[equivalent circuit diagram (model)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YVt9.gif)

**Edit 1:**
Fit-Report:

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 28
    # data points      = 4001
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 1197180.70
    reduced chi-square = 299.444897
    Akaike info crit   = 22816.4225
    Bayesian info crit = 22835.3054
##  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
    L1:  at initial value
    Rp:  at boundary
    Cp:  at initial value
    Cp:  at boundary
[[Variables]]
    C:   2.2e-07 (fixed)
    L1:  1.0000e-05 (init = 1e-05)
    R1:  0.06375191 (fixed)
    Rp:  0.00000000 (init = 10000)
    Cp:  0.10000000 (init = 0.1)
```

**Edit 2:**
Data can be found here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsLKp-1R8HlZhcdlJER5T7qjmvfmnw?e=r8G2nN

**Edit 3:**
I now have simplified my model to a simple RLC-series. With a another set of data this works pretty good. see here the plot [with another set of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v18Aj.png)

```py
def get_elements(params, freq, data):
    C = params['C'].value
    L1 = params['L1'].value
    R1 = params['R1'].value
    #Rp = params['Rp'].value
    #Cp = params['Cp'].value
    #k = params['k'].value
    
    #freq = np.log10(freq)
    
    XC = 1/(1j*2*np.pi*freq*C)
    XL = 1j*2*np.pi*freq*L1
    # XP = 1/(1j*2*np.pi*freq*Cp)
    
    # Z1 = R1*k + XC*Rp/(XC+Rp) + XL
    
    # real = np.real(Z1*XP/(Z1+XP))
    # imag = np.imag(Z1*XP/(Z1+XP))
    
    
    
    Z1 = R1 + XC + XL
    real = np.real(Z1)
    imag= np.imag(Z1)
    
    model = np.sqrt(real**2 + imag**2)
    
    return np.sqrt(np.real(data)**2+np.imag(data)**2) - model

out = minimize(get_elements, params , args=(freq, data))
```

Report:
Chi-Square is really high...

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 25
    # data points      = 4001
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 5.0375e+08
    reduced chi-square = 125968.118
    Akaike info crit   = 46988.8798
    Bayesian info crit = 47001.4684
[[Variables]]
    C:   3.3e-09 (fixed)
    L1:  5.2066e-09 +/- 1.3906e-08 (267.09%) (init = 1e-05)
    R1:  0.40753691 +/- 24.5685882 (6028.56%) (init = 0.05)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(L1, R1) = -0.174
```

With my originally set of data I get this:
[plot original data (complex)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQmn2.png)
Which is not bad, but also not good. That's why I want to make my model more detailed, so I can fit also in higher frequency regions...
Report of this one:

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 25
    # data points      = 4001
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 109156.170
    reduced chi-square = 27.2958664
    Akaike info crit   = 13232.2473
    Bayesian info crit = 13244.8359
[[Variables]]
    C:   2.2e-07 (fixed)
    L1:  2.3344e-08 +/- 1.9987e-10 (0.86%) (init = 1e-05)
    R1:  0.17444702 +/- 0.29660571 (170.03%) (init = 0.05)
```

Please note: I also have changed the input data of the model. Now I give the model complex values and then I calculate the Amplitude. Find this also here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsLKp-1R8HlZhcdlJER5T7qjmvfmnw?e=qnrZk1

Comment: You did include example code - that's great. But you didn't really ask an answerable question: what does "the fit doesn't work right" mean to you?  We don't really need to see the plotting code (though maybe an image of the plot would help), but we would want to see the output of the fit report.   FWIW, I would guess that you could build this as a Model (instead of using `minimize`) but I'm not sure that's the problem you are having. It would also be helpful to show what `freq` and `data` are.   Another general comments: if plotting in log space, maybe fit in log space?

Comment: @M Newville: Thank you for your comment and your tips .

Comment: I've now edited my question and implemented the fit report.
'freq' is the frequency measured along with the 'data', which is the amplitude of the frequency responce of the capacitor.
I'm quite new to this forum, and I don't know how to implement 'freq' and 'data', so that you could see it. But the data is shown in my image attached.

I will also try to fit in log space.

Comment: Are you sure you "connected" the parasitic capacitance of the coil correctly? Some data would be nice. ...and yes, the reduced  chi^2 seems too large, but without knowing the data....

Comment: Hello, I have now included some download links for the data (this is the only option I know, when this can be done better please let me know).

@mikuszefski Actually I think I have connected all elements correctly - did I made a mistake? ...didn't included the Cstr in my model, if you mean this

Comment: Hi, 2 issues here. 1: Data seems to be in some type of dB so `20 Log10( V )` but not normalized. If you fit this with your amplitude function that will not work. 2: Without `C_str` there is no load and nothing to measure. What am I missing in your circuit? I would expect a reference resistor to ground or something like this.

Comment: BTW, considering the frequency range it is likely that the Ohmic resistance of the coil is not constant but increases with frequency due to skin and proximity effects

Comment: Thanks again for your answers.
I have edited my question, please see above "Edit 3". 
The input data is now complex. I also simplified the model to an simple RLC series. 
My actual goal is to find a model which fits most of my data (all are Capacitors), also in higher frequency regions. The model must not be a physical one, for me this idea was only logical....Do you have an idea how I can make a better model in higher regions step by step? What would you do as next step?

Comment: a) don't have initial values at boundaries, b) replace max=10e20 with max=np.inf (or max=None)